# android daemon thread after thread exits out of a while loop

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, message-queue

Been having an issues that has been bugging me the whole day.
Consider the following. This worker thread reads in chars to parse commands until the boolean _readingEnabled is false. The thread should terminate, but when I look at the debugger, it becomes a daemon thread and it causes problems down the line since there should only be one connection at all times. Ideally the thread should restart as a new thread by reconnecting and no other duplicate thread should exist.

```
FileDownloaderActivity extends Activity{
    TelnetClient _telnet;
    Inputstream _in;
    Outputstream _out;
    boolean _readingEnabled = true;
    onCreate(){
               startReadThread();
              }

    startReadThread(){
              Thread readingThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
              run(){
              //connect _telnet, _in and _out
              while(true){
                  if (_readingEnabled){
                     char c = in.read();
                     //some string operations
                    }
                 else{
                     break;
                    }
              }
              print("reading thread exited");
              _readingEnabled = true ; //the thread will be restarted
              });
            }
             readingThread.start();
              }
}
```

I have this other worker thread that starts the download of files within a function of the FileDownloaderActivity. The handler is bound to the UI thread(does it matter?). The message does get executed successfully.

```
downloadFiles(){
        Handler handler = new Handler(){ //part of the UI thread execution
            void handleMessage(Message m){
                startReadThread(); //restart the reading thread
          }
     }

        Thread downloaderThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            run(){    
                _readingEnabled = false; //should kick out of the while loop in the other thread
               //download files...
              handler.sendMessage(new Message()); 
               }
        });
    }
```

The behavior that I observe is that a new ReadingThread starts executing  before the old ReadingThread terminates. The old ReadingThread does print out "reading thread exited" but it becomes a daemon thread. If I go ahead and do another set of downloaded files, I end up with two daemon reading threads and so on until the connection fails badly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If the only place you're setting `_readingEnabled = false` is in `downloaderThread.run()` then you can just let the readingThread run indefinitely, i.e.

```
          while(true){
              if (_readingEnabled){
                 char c = in.read();
                 //some string operations
                }
             else{
                 Thread.sleep(100);
                }
          }
```

If you're application is using sockets, you might have more success using [Netty](http://netty.io/).

From the Netty home page:

> Netty is a NIO client server framework which enables quick and easy development of network applications such as protocol servers and clients. It greatly simplifies and streamlines network programming such as TCP and UDP socket server.

Comment: I wanted to terminate the reading thread to avoid socket exceptions. The nature of the server I communicate with using telnet, for some reason, leaves my telnet client in a bad state, which is solved by a reconnection(hence the new thread). Any ideas why I am left with daemon threads? I will try your suggestion tomorrow. Thanks, I appreciate your input :)

Comment: Hmmm, well, maybe you don't need to use a `Thread`, if you're just using the `Thread` to download some file and then terminating it, then perhaps use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). It will allow you to perform your download, once done, you can update your UI, and/or do any processing you need.